# Django admin panel doesn't work after modify default user model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I was trying to extend user profile. I founded a few solutions, but the most recommended was to create new user class containing foreign key to original django.contrib.auth.models.User class. I did it with [this](http://pyxx.org/2008/08/18/how-to-extend-user-model-in-django-and-enable-new-fields-in-newforms-admin/) so i have in `models.py`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(verify_exists=False)
```

and in my `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from someapp.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

# Define an inline admin descriptor for UserProfile model
class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile
    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1

# Define a new UserAdmin class
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline, ]

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

And now when I'm trying to create/edit user in admin panel i have an error:
`"Unknown column 'content_userprofile.id' in 'field list'"` where content is my appname.

I was trying to add line `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'content.UserProfile'` to my `settings.py` but with no effect.

How to tell panel admin to know how to correctly display fields in user form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some effort I found working solution:

1. the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'content.UserProfile'` is required
2. please drop your database (auth_user, yourapp_userprofile tables should be enough)
3. finally `python manage.py syncdb`